# Images get cut in a slide show on resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a slide show but my images cuts when I resize the screen
how can I make it responsive..I want some thing to be done in the javascript code,I have also try to get the width of the container and resize images accordingly but its not working

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 0px;">
            <div id="slider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide img-responsive" src="Images/free1.jpg" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide img-responsive" src="Images/free2.jpg" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide img-responsive" src="Images/free3.jpg" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide img-responsive" src="Images/free4.jpg" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide img-responsive" src="Images/free5.jpg" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide img-responsive" src="Images/free1.jpg" /></li>

                </ul>

            </div>


        </div>


    </div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
    var width = 1160;
    var animationSpeed = 2000;
    var pause = 1000;
    var currentSlide = 1;


    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');
    var interval;
    /*
    function get_width(width) {
        if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 450px)").matches) {
            width == 450;
        } else if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 750px)").matches) {

            width == 700;

        } else {

            width == 1160;

        }

        return width;

    }*/
    function startSlider() {

        interval = setInterval(function () {

            $slideContainer.animate({ 'margin-left': '-=' + width  }, animationSpeed, function () {
                currentSlide++;
                if (currentSlide == $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }


            });

        }, pause);
    }
    function stopSlider() {

        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    //listen for mouse enter and pause
    $slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);




    startSlider();



});




#slider {
width:100%;
height:400px;
  overflow:hidden;



}
    #slider .slides {
    display:block;
    width:8000px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   

    }
    #slider .slide {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
   width:1160px;
   height:400px;    
    }

 li {
list-style-type:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max-width: 100%;` to your `<img>`. Example:

```
.slides img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to set the image width based on `#slider` width, you can use this:

```
$('.slide').each(function() {
  $(this).width($('#slider').width());
});
```

And if you want to re-set the images when window resized, you can handle window resize event. Example:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.slide').each(function() {
      $(this).width($('#slider').width());
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried that but the problem is that in javascript code I have fixed the width to 1160 size the size of the slier is reponsive but the image inside is not..can u help me how to change the width of image according to size of screen in jquery/javascript

Comment: images cut from the right side of the slide show on reducing size of screen

Comment: thanks for your reply but my problem remains the same tried everything here but still my images are cutting if i resize the browser